# Openmp creates many threads but seems to use only one core

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I'm trying to use OpenMP to parallelize a for loop in Fortran.

It seems to work fine, it definitely creates the right number of threads and goes much faster than the original serial version.

However, the %CPU usage is huge, making me worry that the threads are being concentrated on just one or two cores (as opposed to examples I've seen online where each thread appears with its own PID).

```
$ export omp_num_threads=12
$ nohup ./z90nr&
$ ps aurx
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
ty       25350 7771  0.0 1564928 26868 pts/9   Rl   14:18 169:40 ./z90nr
```

Is this a problem, and if so, how can I fix it? 
I tried setting GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY, this did not solve the problem.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

No; this is just the difference between threads and processes.

[Threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) all exist within one [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29); so there's only one PID.  And the large %CPU is simply how these numbers are reported; >100% here indicates that there's definitely more than one CPU being used.  The `top` command is helpful here;  If you run `top -H` you should be able to see each thread individually, and if you press <kbd>1</kbd> while it's running you'll be able to see the CPU use per-CPU, which will also help disaggregate all the running threads.

Comment: Actually threads are different LWPs and each has a separate Task ID but the same PID. I don't remember how one can make `ps` print the TIDs.

Answer (score 2):

Note that OpenMP defines all its environment variables as all upper case and on Unix the environment is case sensitive, e.g. `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is not the same as `omp_num_threads`. It appears to me that your program probably runs with way more than 12 threads, I would say 80 threads given the 7771% CPU usage (are you running on a system with 8 10-core CPUs?). By default `libgomp` (the GNU OpenMP runtime) uses as much threads as is the number of available logical CPUs.

You can instruct `ps` to show the individual LWPs in each process via the `H` or `m` option, e.g. `ps auxrm`. With `m` fields that have the same value for all LWPs are replaced by dashes, e.g.:

```
USER     PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
hristo   529  188  3.9 3078268 2574692 pts/21 -   15:16   0:03 ./omp_memset2
hristo     - 55.5    -      -     - -        Rl+  15:16   0:01 -
hristo     -  0.0    -      -     - -        Sl+  15:16   0:00 -
hristo     - 39.0    -      -     - -        Rl+  15:16   0:00 -
hristo     - 36.0    -      -     - -        Rl+  15:16   0:00 -
hristo     - 56.5    -      -     - -        Rl+  15:16   0:01 -
```

With `H` these fields have actual values, but because they are sampled at different time instants, the values could be different (which is not the case as all LWPs share the same process page table and hence cannot have different values for things like the resident set size). This is also why the individual `%CPU` values do not add up to the `%CPU` value for the whole process.